how to deploy a mern stack application on the github?
To troubleshoot the 404 error while deploying my full-stack MERN app on Vercel.com, I've tried several steps, but I'm still encountering issues. I suspect that the problem may be related to my .env file. Could you suggest some modifications I can make to my (package.json) , (package-lock.json), .env file, or any other aspect of my project to resolve this issue? Thank you for your help.
remove 404 error while deploying full stack MERN stack app on vercel.com.
